# Dependency Injection not working when defining module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular so please let me know my absolute newbie mistake I am making here.

I have a module and controller as such

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('myController', MyController);
```

I removed most of the code for brevity, just showing the relevant parts.

This code works perfect, the page loads and everything functions as expected.

However my problem comes when I want to inject something into the module

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp', ['custom'])
        .controller('myController', MyController);
```

When I do this, my page doesn't load at all and I have no errors in the console output.

So I originally thought it was the custom module not loading properly, so I tried this

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp', [])
        .controller('myController', MyController);
```

This doesn't even work, same again in that nothing loads, with empty square brackets, even though I see many examples like this.

I am using AngularJS 1.3.16.

Comment: Just to confirm, You can only define your module once. Are you sure module is not redefined? Where have you defined `custom`?

Comment: Does your html has the **ng-app** attribute somewhere? Like `<body ng-app="myApp">`

Comment: Its only defined once. My project is really small at the moment and I am using angular.js not min.js but no difference. But shouldn't it work with empty brackets as well? I removed custom and just had empty brackets in there and it still didn't work, which means it is something else.

Comment: @MikeSW no ng-app, I use angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);

As I mentioned above though, everything works perfectly if I don't have those [] in parameters.

Comment: Whenever you use the [] in the line angular.module('myApp', []) you are defining the module 'myApp'. It doesn't matter if it's empty (no dependencies) or not empty ('custom' as a dependency). So if the code is working without the [] like angular.module(myApp') it means you have defined the module 'myApp' somewhere else on your code.

Comment: thanks @dluz - it was defined elsewhere.

Comment: sorry @Satpal it was defined elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `angular.module('myApp', [])`: defines a new app which overrides the previous definition.
- `angular.module('myApp')`: retrieve the existing app.

When you use `angular.module('myApp')`, it runs well. So there must be somewhere in your code shows: `angular.module('myApp', [])`.

`angular.module('myApp', ['custom'])` makes the page not working, because this new definition overrides the previous one.

Check https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Comment: I didn't realize that you could define them more than once.